# Why are my PDF files not working when downloading them as email attachments?

Tags: python-3.x, email, pdf, email-attachments, imaplib

I'm trying to download PDF attachments in specific emails that I receive using imaplib in Python. The code itself seems to be working fine. All the documents I want are being downloaded just the way I want them to, but all the downloaded PDF documents simply don't work. I can't open them, and they don't seem to work with PdfReader (Python module). They are also larger in file size than they should be. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here is the code I have:

```
import imaplib
import base64
import os
import email

user = 'my email'
passwd = 'my password'
directory = 'directory I want my downloaded files to go to'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(user, passwd)
mail.select('INBOX')

res, data = mail.search(None, 'FROM "email I want to download attachments from" SUBJECT "subject I want"')
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()

for num in data[0].split():
    res, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = data[0][1]
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()
        
        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(directory, fileName)

            if not os.path.isfile(filePath):
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

Whenever I try to open any of the PDF files (using Zathura) I get the following messages in my terminal:

> error: cannot recognize version marker
>
> warning: trying to repair broken xref
>
> warning: repairing PDF document
>
> warning: name is too long
>
> warning: ...repeated 1376 times...
>
> error: no objects found
>
> error: could not open document

Also, opening the PDF files in a browser does not work either. I tried opening them with Google Chrome and I simply get a message that says:

> Error
> Failed to load PDF document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (use `email.parser`?)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, now my PDF documents can be opened and they also work with PdfReader. Here's how the code looks like now that it is working:

```
import imaplib
import os
import email

user = 'email'
passwd = 'password'
directory = 'path to directory I want my downloaded files to go to'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(user, passwd)
mail.select('INBOX')

res, data = mail.search(None, 'FROM "email I want to download attachments from" SUBJECT "Subject filter"')
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()

for num in data[0].split():
    res, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

    for part in raw_email.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()
        
        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(directory, fileName)

            if not os.path.isfile(filePath):
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

Turns out the base64 module was not even needed since part of what broke my PDF files was decoding the byte data to UTF-8